# Javascript is not working in my editor

Tags: javascript

I'm kind of new in javascript . here is my strange problem.
when i write some code in my editor `Phpstorm` and want to see my effect nothating happend but when i put my code in firebug it works !!!

here's my little code :

```
var views = document.getElementById("views-row");
console.log("This is element type of :" , views.nodeType);
console.log("This is element type of :" , views.innerHTML);
console.log("This is element type of :" , views.childNodes);

var myLinks = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
console.log("Links", myLinks.length);

var views = document.getElementById("views-row");

views.setAttribute("align","right");
```

am i missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because you are rendering the javascript before the `HTML` page is rendered. Your HTML tags aren't known by the `DOM`. You should use an `ondomready` function or just place your javascript before the closing `</body>` tag and it should work.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <!-- your HTML here -->

<script>
(function() {
   // Dom is ready execute your javascript functions here!

})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**On dom ready example (be aware, this doesn't work in all browsers):**

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  var state = document.readyState
  if (state == 'complete') {
      // Dom is ready
  }
}​
```

If you really want to load your javascript inside your `<head>` tag. Take at look a jQuery, then you can make use of a crossbrowser `domready` event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

Comment: Thx . it works , one more question : why is it so important to put javascript code top of the code (in header) or in body .  
when i put my script code in header is not working and when i put it in body it works . why ?

Comment: Like I said, your HTML isn't rendered yet. You are executing a getElementById("view-rows"), but this element does not yet exists. So if you load it after the HTML is rendered, it does exist. I hope this makes sense :)

Comment: Yes it helps a lot . thx a million

Answer (score 1):

You should wayt for the content to be loaded!
If you run this code in the head like this, it will be executed before your DOM-Elements are loaded.
You can attach an eventhandler to the event that the content is loaded:

```
document.addEventListener("load", function(){
    //your code here
}, false);
```

In this case you can leave your code in the head which is more accurate.

Comment: why more accurate? It's better to load it before the closing </body> tag. Read more about this on [developer.yahoo.com](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom)

Comment: I just read it, thanks! 
I learned to allways put in the head.